# how to show json one per view pager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am developing a short news app.when the user swipes up the view pager changes and loads new view pager. Can I show one list item per view pager, on swipe on next view pager show another item.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Nasim. Did you use `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` together or maybe with `Fragment`s? I mean, how did you implement your layout? Would you paste the layout codes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created and uploaded a sample android project to GitHub for your problem.

[Use this link](https://github.com/anupa91/ViewPagerExample2) (https://github.com/anupa91/ViewPagerExample2)

Comment: i am not able to add JSON data can you please modify the git by adding JSON data from a URL; thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Nasim,
"adding JSON data from a URL" you mean you need an example to call an endpoint and get the JSON response and save it in your bean?

Comment: yes, can you please modify it like that. I tried modifying I get too many errors. I am a beginner to android. Thanks for your support.

Comment: OK, Nasim,
I'll update it and let you know.

Comment: Have Uploaded It

Comment: Hi Nisam,
Sorry for the delay, I have updated the GitHub repository with a sample API call.

Comment: hi, anupa thanks for your help. can you please help me once more. I have created a code which parses data from JSON. can please tell me how to add this parsed list to beannews list. please help. My JSON Parsing code https://pastebin.com/dPtyQ9Qn

Comment: Its my pleasure Nasim. What do you mean by 'add this list to beannews list'?

Comment: Nasim, Use GSon library as I used in the shared repository, Using that you can parse your JSON to your BeanNews list very easily. To add GSon for your project please add ' implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5' ' dependency to your app level gradle and use Gson like I used in that shared project. (MainActivity: Line No: 113 - 114)

Comment: thanks for your response. i want to add the values which i have parsed from the json https://pastebin.com/dPtyQ9Qn. i have parsed some values like creator name,imageurl etcc. in that code. how can add this to the beannews list. thanks for your support.